# Redirect Enter press in detailsview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, insert, keypress, detailsview

When using a scanner to insert into a detailsview the scanner scans and then presses enter. How do I either redirect the enter to be a tab, or just stop the enter key from triggering the insert method?